# A blue division is not covering enough space as compared to course instructors screen

Tags: html, css

I am currently doing a full-stack web development course, and at one point I realized that my blue div(the part with the mountains, clouds and the "im aadesh a programmer") is not covering as much space as it needed to.

[Angela(course instructor)'s webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90JIJ.png)

[My webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06s1Y.png)

My code can be found here: https://github.com/RedMatte/help (ignore the dawwdwadawd.html file)

Comment: What is blue div there? maybe I'm colorblind.

Comment: the part with the mountains, clouds and the "im aadesh a programmer"

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100vh` to the blue div for it to cover the whole screen.

Comment: Thank you, but that makes the cloud go under the mountain and the mountain is not touching the bottom of the blue div. I have tried this before.